# How to add pre/post methods to class. Python

Tags: python, oop, polymorphism

Lets assume I've a class A which has a bunch of methods, but I want it to run certain lines before and after each method is called.
For example: I want my class Dog here to run before() and after() every time bark() or run() are been called.

```
class Dog():
    def __init__(self, sound, speed):
        self.sound = sound
        self.speed = speed

    def before(self):
        check_some_things(self)

    def after(self):
        do_some_things(self)

    def bark(self):
        sound(self.sound)

    def run(self):
        move(self.speed)
```

Comment: If these are going to be hard-coded into your class, why not just hard code them into the methods? So before `sound(self.sound)` have `self.before()`.

Comment: Assume I have 20 methods, I find it silly the same code runs at the first/last line of each method.
Even more, lets imagine MegaDog inherent from dog, and I want before()/after() run for MegaDog's methods as well.

Comment: I'm not sure  but can we use context manager here, as it has a clean way to execute at start and end method of execution for any method.

Answer (score 7):

You could encapsulate this in a decorator; the following decorator will call `before` and `after` if these are available on `self`:

```
import inspect
from functools import wraps

def before_and_after(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kw):
        if hasattr(self, 'before') and inspect.ismethod(self.before):
            self.before()
        result = f(self, *args, **kw)
        if hasattr(self, 'after') and inspect.ismethod(self.after):
            self.after()
        return result
    return wrapper
```

then simply apply to the methods that should be wrapped:

```
class Dog():
    def __init__(self, sound, speed):
        self.sound = sound
        self.speed = speed

    def before(self):
        check_some_things(self)

    def after(self):
        do_some_things(self)

    @before_and_after
    def bark(self):
        sound(self.sound)

    @before_and_after
    def run(self):
        move(self.speed)
```

The decorator assumes it is used on methods, e.g. the produced wrapper expects `self` as a first argument.

If this needs to apply to *all* methods that are not `before` or `after`, perhaps a metaclass is in order:

```
class BeforeAfterMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, classname, bases, body):
        for name, value in body.items():
            if not inspect.isfunction(value):
                continue
            if name in ('before', 'after') or name[:2] + name[-2:] == '_' * 4:
                # before or after hook, or a special method name like __init__.
                continue
            body[name] = before_and_after(value)
        return super(BeforeAfterMeta, mcs).__new__(mcs, classname, bases, body)
```

which you then can apply to your class:

```
class Dog(metaclass=BeforeAfterMeta):
    def __init__(self, sound, speed):
        self.sound = sound
        self.speed = speed

    def before(self):
        check_some_things(self)

    def after(self):
        do_some_things(self)

    def bark(self):
        sound(self.sound)

    def run(self):
        move(self.speed)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a decorator function to inspect your `class Dog` if the pre and post methods exists and override the `run` method:

```
def PrePostMethod(inputClass):
    mainRun    = inputClass.run
    beforeFunc = inputClass.before if "before" in inputClass.__dict__ else None
    afterFunc  = inputClass.after if "after" in inputClass.__dict__ else None
    def new_run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # you could inspect the given arguments if you need
        # to parse arguments into before and the after methods
        if beforeFunc:
            self.before()
        mainRun(self)
        if afterFunc:
            self.after()
    inputClass.run = new_run
    return inputClass

@PrePostMethod
class Dog(object):

    def __init__(self, sound, speed):
        self.sound = sound
        self.speed = speed

    def before(self):
        print "Do stuff before"

    def after(self):
        print "Do stuff after"

    def run(self):
        print "Do main process"


Dog(1,2).run()
```

To parse arguments and keywords arguments from `run` into `before` and `after`, use the class `inspect` and loop through the args and kwargs to parse the right ones.

```
from inspect import getargspec
def argHandler(method, *args, **kwargs):
    method  = getargspec(method)
    mArgs   = method.args
    mKwargs = method.keywords
    rArgs    =  args[:len(mArgs)-1]
    rKwargs  = { k:v for k,v in kwargs.iteritems() if k in mKwargs }
    leftArgs = len(mArgs)-len(rArgs)
    if len(rKwargs):
        rKwargs = [ rKwargs[k] for k in mArgs[:leftArgs-1]]
        rArgs  += rKwargs
    return rArgs

def PrePostMethod(inputClass):
    mainRun    = inputClass.run
    beforeFunc = inputClass.before if "before" in inputClass.__dict__ else None
    afterFunc  = inputClass.after if "after" in inputClass.__dict__ else None
    def new_run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if beforeFunc:
            nargs = argHandler(self.before, *args, **kwargs)
            if nargs: self.before( *nargs)
            else: self.before()
        nargs = argHandler(mainRun, *args, **kwargs)
        if nargs: mainRun(self, *nargs)
        else: mainRun(self)
        if afterFunc:
            nargs = argHandler(self.after, *args, **kwargs)
            if nargs:  self.after( *nargs)
            else: self.after()
    inputClass.run = new_run
    return inputClass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use many different ways to do this. But I think the best way is, to define a class with the Pre- and Post-Methods and redefine it's object hidden methods: `__enter__` and `__exit__`. To use them, just call the class with the compound statement `with`.

```
 class pre_post(object):

    def __enter__(self):
        print "Enter check method.."

    def __exit__(self, type, value, tb):
        print "Exit check method.."

class dog(object):

    def run(self, checkups=True):
        if checkups:
            with pre_post() as pp:
                print "My stuff.."
        else:
            print "My stuff.."

dog().run(True)
```

This will give you the following result:

```
Enter check method..
My stuff..
Exit check method..
```

I hope that will help you.